# Xamarin.Android PushNotification

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a Xamarin android app with GCM push notifications using this plugin:

https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification

I followed the instructions in the readme page and changed ***ANDROID SENDER ID*** with my google project number (obtained from the google developer console).

I can successfully register the device using the ***Register*** function (the ***OnRegisteredfunction*** on the ***CrossPushNotificationListener*** class is fired and a valid registration token is returned).

To send a notification I used this tool (because i don't have a backend up and running):

http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

I filled:

- The ***Device Token*** field either with the token obtained with the
  previous device registration or with "/topics/global"
- The ***Message*** field with a random message
- The ***Api Key*** with a Server API Key generated from the google
  developer console

The app never reaches the *OnMessage* and nothing seems to be received.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I never used this plugin, but if you only want to have Android notifications, you might want to get GCMService from Xamarin components (Google Cloud Messaging Client), and create a custom listener that extends it. But before switching solution, did you check that you are compiling on API21+, and that all the required packages were installed using the SDK manager ?

Comment: Hi 

I'm the author of this plugin, could you provide some code snippet of the push notifications code in your project? to be able to look more into it of what might be missing.

Comment: @rendy Hi! I followed these steps to create my app:

1- I created a new Xamarin.Forms Portable App
2- I modified the Android project settings in the solution this way:

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/lQnFf.png

3- I added to the PCL the ***CrossPushNotificationListener*** class (copying it from the readme page) and modified the ***MainActivity*** class in the Android project:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/gmoJZ.png

Comment: You are unregistering after registering so you will never get a push notification dont unregister

Comment: @rendy Sorry that line of code was not supposed to be there, it was only one of my attempts to verify if the OnUnregistered method was called. I tried without that line but still nothing happens. The OnRegistered method gets fired, but the the OnMessage is never reached.

Comment: you can test using [pushtry.com][1]


  [1]: http://www.pushtry.com/